# How can I get 'git log' to display filenames?

Tags: git, git-log

Which command should I use (in Git Bash) to display a history of commits, comments, user, date, and *most importantly* the file name?

Comment: By "gitbash" I presume you mean "Git on a system that isn't Windows"?

Comment: Git bash is a msys shell included in "git for windows"

Comment: Never heard it referred to like that before, since "Bash" is a shell commonly found on Linux and Mac.  In either event, I would genuinely doubt that the commands would be much different between the versions.

Comment: It is called Git bash because it is a special version of bash for windows that was specifically made to implement a Git command line interface for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log --stat` will show the detailed history and will also show which files were changed in each commit.

If you want to further customize the output from `git log`, check [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for configuration details.

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --name-only
```

or

```
git log --name-status
```

will show you the file names modified. The difference between the two is that `--name-only` will only display file names, while `--name-status` will have an additional letter before the name indicating the files's status, i.e.,

- A - Added
- M - Modified
- D - Deleted

There are some additional ones for renames and copies, but these are not as common as the three listed here.